# TextView nullPointerException onItemClick - content view has been set

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

For my Activity, I have a textview that I'm wanting the text to change onItemClick from a GridView. For the life of me, I can't figure out why it keeps creating a nullPointerException when I click on the gridview Item to change the text of the textview. The "instrucitontextview" is the text view in question, and I'm changing the text at the bottom of the onItemClick.

I have the contentView set, so it should be able to reference the layout correctly. I have it decalred in the onCreate, so there should be no referencing issues. Really at a loss here.

**Activity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jungle_activity);

final TextView instructiontextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_jungle_instructions);

final GridView gridviewNeutrals = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.jungle_gridview_neutrals);

gridviewNeutrals.setAdapter(new JungleImageAdapterNeutral(
            getApplicationContext()));

gridviewNeutrals.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View imageview,
                int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                if (!JungleTimerService.baronJungleTimerStarted) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "baron jungle started");
                    JungleTimerService.baronJungleTimerStarted = true;
                    textviewArrayListIndex();
                    createBaronTimer();
                    mServer.baronJungleTimer();
                    TextView name = (TextView) imageview
                            .findViewById(R.id.jungle_grid_custom_text);
                    name.setTextSize(13);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams llp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    name.setLayoutParams(llp);
                    imageview
                            .setPadding(
                                    (int) getResources()
                                            .getDimensionPixelSize(
                                                    R.dimen.jungle_timer_button_pressed_dp),
                                    (int) getResources()
                                            .getDimensionPixelSize(
                                                    R.dimen.jungle_timer_button_pressed_dp),
                                    (int) getResources()
                                            .getDimensionPixelSize(
                                                    R.dimen.jungle_timer_button_pressed_dp),
                                    (int) getResources()
                                            .getDimensionPixelSize(
                                                    R.dimen.jungle_timer_button_pressed_dp));
                    instructiontextview.setText("worked");
                }
            }
```

**Logcat**

```
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at com.divinityworks.leaguecentral_leagueoflegends.JungleActivity$3.onItemClick(JungleActivity.java:164)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1268)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3059)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3950)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
07-09 10:56:42.826: E/AndroidRuntime(7992):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Jungle_activity.xml**

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/jungle_scrollview_timers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout_jungle_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_jungle_inner_scrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jungle_textview_instructions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/textview_jungle_instructions"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks

Comment: `TextView name = (TextView) imageview
                            .findViewById(R.id.jungle_grid_custom_text)` must be null check if name is null

Comment: which line gives you the exception?

Comment: Added the logcat and updated the description. The instructionTextView is the textview that I am having issues with. The "name" textview in the onItemClick of the gridview works fine.

Comment: do you have textview with id `textview_jungle_instructions` in `jungle_activity`. also whats on  line 168 `JungleActivity.java`.?

Comment: Added xml to description. Yes, the textview is created with id `textview_jungle_instructions` in `jungle_activity` and line 168 in `JungleActivity.java` is part of the `onItemClick` but for position 1 (the position in the description is position 0). `JungleTimerService.dragonJungleTimerStarted = true;`

Comment: @Razgriz231 check the answer and give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this

```
final TextView instructiontextview =
(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_jungle_instructions);
```

But you have this in xml

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jungle_textview_instructions"
```

You don't have a textview with id `textview_jungle_instructions` in your xml.

Since textview is not initialized you will get `NullPointerException`.

So it should be

```
final TextView instructiontextview = 
(TextView) findViewById(R.id.jungle_textview_instructions);
```

Comment: Sigh, Thanks for the help. Such a dumb mistake. Suppose that's what I get for naming text strings almost the same as the textviews id.